# How do I print a PDF in iOS?

Tags: ios, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF from a URL in iOS.  I can get the print dialog to show up, but the job fails with error code 3.  Is what I'm trying possible, or do I have to download the PDF first?

**printUrl**

```
-(void) printUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    pic.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"Printing from URL: %@", url);
    if ([UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url]]) {
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = [url lastPathComponent];
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        pic.printInfo = printInfo;
        pic.showsPageRange = YES;
        pic.printingItem = url;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            //self.content = nil;
            NSLog(@"Print job %@", (completed ? @"completed" : @"didn't complete"));
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %ld", error.domain, (long)error.code);
            }
        };

        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't print specified URL");
    }
}
```

**Log output**

```
<Warning>: Printing from url: http://www.energy.umich.edu/sites/default/files/pdf-sample.pdf
<Warning>: Can print: Yes
<Warning>: -[PKPaperList matchedPaper:preferBorderless:withDuplexMode:didMatch:] paperToMatch=<PKPaper: 0x187e4320> result=<PKPaper: 0x187d9ba0> matchType=0
<Warning>: Print job completed
<Warning>: FAILED! due to error in domain UIPrintErrorDomain with error code 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a pretty dumb mistake on this one.  I was passing in the URL as an NSString instead of the required NSURL.